# Pandas and matplotlib not showing proper dates as Index, title issue and app crashes

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

My code used to generate a graph based on a CSV is not working as expected.
The first issue is that if I run the code straightfrom the IDLE to generate the graph it works, but if I just run the script.py python app craches. 
The second is, the dates are not showing the correct format (format is DD-MM-YYYY) or not showing at all, any idea why?
The third one is, the title is very far from the plots. How could i fix it?

My code is:

```
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time


## dd/mm/yyyy format
today = (time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))

df = pandas.read_csv('data.csv', delimiter=';', 
                     index_col=0, 
                     parse_dates=[0], dayfirst=True, 
                     names=['Date','1','2','3','4', '5'])
df.plot()
df.plot(subplots=True, marker='.',markersize=6, title ="test %s " % (today), fontsize = 11, figsize=(8, 20))



plt.savefig('sampledata15.png')
```

Graph is:
[image]

Thanks a lot for your inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer a couple of your questions:

Pandas automatically uses the best date format for you. You have a couple of month of data so it chooses the date format you see. Also as all plots share the same dates, so the dates are only shown in the lowest graph only.

To get rid of the extra space, remove the df.plot() command.

Comment: Thank you @Serbitar. Remove the df plot didnt help. The title is still very far from the Plots.. any idea why? Thanks again.